# Make or Prepare Food?

Tags: verbs

Which one is more suitable: Make or Prepare food? I'm really confused between these two.

Comment: Both are fine, it depends on what you want to say. You can also  say **make / prepare a dish** and **make / prepare something to eat**. Please look up the terms *make* and *prepare*  in a dictionary and explain where your confusion lies. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to specify what variety of English you want people to answer for, there is some difference , I believe, to the situations in which American-English speakers and British English speakers would use 'make' in relation to food. Americans seem to 'make' eggs in situations where Brits 'cook' them, though the distinction is not universal. eg https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=n4jZqbMK4e8C&pg=PT331&lpg=PT331&dq=%22make+eggs%22+-how&source=bl&ots=u93ey3bsk6&sig=4PYw9X67gtI5q8JCMFnuiCWhln4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR5Jzt9sTTAhUoJ8AKHaE1CAkQ6AEIOTAF#v=onepage&q=%22make%20eggs%22%20-how&f=false

Comment: Also, it isn't an either/or situation, there are many other words which people might use in relation to food preparations, and one person's preferred usage may not be another's. Your best bet may be to look up examples of both usages and see what general patterns you can detect for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prepare: ready for cooking or eating (Oxford)

make: = prepare

They are synonyms if regarding food/drink.
Make tends to be used more with the informal spoken language so you may hear...
'I’ll make us a nice cuppa' rather than 'I’ll prepare us a nice cuppa' (cuppa = cup of tea).

Answer (score 0):

preparing is more formal, you usually say make-making with friends

Comment: Can you please give some explanation as to why you think preparing is more formal?